# D3js - filter column from csv

Tags: d3.js, filter, boxplot

I have a boxplot which is part of a Dashboard. The boxplot is based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jensgrubert/7789216) example. What I want is that the corresponding bar from the boxplot is highlighted when the user selects an element from another graphic of the dashboard (and the other way around). How can I just select one element from the boxplot? Until now I did the filtering by using e.g

```
svg.selectAll(".box").filter(function(d) { return d.name == "name1" })
```

But in this case I filtered a row from the csv and now I need to filter a column ... I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: It depends on how you created the columns and rows, can you share more code?

Comment: How do you mean this? I have the same code as in the linked example. My csv is also looking like the one in the example.